# JQuery enabling button if all checkboxes are selected and add css to disabled button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to enable a button if all checkboxes are selected and disable it if any are unselected. I have achived this by using this code:

```
checkBoxes.change(function() {
    submitButton.attr("disabled", checkBoxes.is(":not(:checked)"));
 });
```

What I am not sure about is how to add and remove a css class if the button is enabled or disabled.

Example here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lilu/5NDY4/2/)

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you unsure about? You are already deciding if the button should be enabled or disabled, surely it's not that hard to... tell if it's enabled or disabled?

Comment: I am unsure how to add and remove the css class based on whether the button is disabled or not. I have tried to add a check to see if the button has the attribute 'disabled' but it did not work.

Comment: You are just repeating the same thing. Let me help: which part of `if (button is disabled) { add class } else { remove class }` are you unsure about? Also note you should be using `.prop` instead of `.attr` here.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5NDY4/4/

Comment: @Prashank you can post that as a answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer now...

```
var checkBoxes = $('input.compulsory'),
    submitButton = $('#continue');

checkBoxes.change(function () {
    submitButton.attr("disabled", checkBoxes.is(":not(:checked)"));
    if(checkBoxes.is(":not(:checked)")) {
        submitButton.addClass('disabled');
    } else {
        submitButton.removeClass('disabled');
    }       
});
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/5NDY4/4/)